# UITableViewCell textLabel is not vertically aligned when I change font

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have table view in my app. It is inside storyboard, and is configured to have prototype cells. Firstly I used textLabel property of UITableViewCell to set text and also changed it's font inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:,

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibre-Light" size:18];
```

and when I change font the text already is not vertically centred, look at screenshots. 
[image]
[image]

First picture is with custom font, second picture is with default font.

I tried to create label inside prototype cell and define constraint to make it vertically centre aligned.

[image]

But that also didn't helped, the result is the same as in first screenshots. Why I get this kind of behaviour??

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

After several days of torture I finally found a workaround.
First of all let me not, that the font that I was using was the source of the problem. When you align it vertically it does't align, simply may be because it has some kind of margins in the bottom, so the only way to solve may problem was to position the label inside the view manually so the resulting position will cause the UILabel inside UITableViewCell appear vertically aligned. But again I was trying to move the label lower by hand inside Interface Builder But again no success. Here is the image of interface builder prototype cells in the lower right corner and the result of that positioning in the background

[image]

Notice that the label hasn't moved, but was cropped from the top. Again frustration... why doesn't it move??? If I manually position it inside the interface builder. Finally I just thought may be the label is not correctly sized? So inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I just called [textLabel sizeToFit], and everything worked.

So as a conclusion, beware that sometime custom fonts may function not the way that you wanted, because of their inner implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to fixing your custom font

http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

Summary of changes

- Download the Apple Font Tool Suite
- Terminal: ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf
- XML file created in the directory
- Open XML with Text Editor and adjust the settings of ascender, descender
- Terminal:ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf
- Add custom font to your projekt(dont forget plist item)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make the label stretch from the top edge of the cell.contentView to the bottom edge? This is the default with non-custom cells. In my experience this has always worked as expected.

Comment: I'll try that. Only didn't understand then why changing the font of default textLabel the text again isn't center aligned.

Comment: That could be because the center of the maximum size letter is not the same between fonts.

Comment: I guess then you have to tweak. I.e. reduce reduce the top margin until you are satisfied. Custom font --> custom formatting.

Comment: I tried that also, no success. I'll post the answer as soon as I find the solution. Thanks Mundi!!

Comment: Wait - it is impossible this does not work. You can also shift the label down until the text has the desired position.

Comment: Look the answer that I'll post, with detailed description.